# Help with a Trigger for Counting Activities

Tags: trigger, activity

I need some help with a trigger I'm trying to write (being not a developer). But I'd like to do two things:

1. Only have the trigger run for completed tasks
2. Only run if the subject is "Call"

Here's my code, but unsure where to insert these criteria:

```
trigger TaskUpdateLead on Task (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update) {

    Set<ID> LeadIds = new Set<ID>();


    String leadPrefix = Lead.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();


    if(trigger.new!=null){
        for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
            if (t.WhoId!= null && string.valueof(t.WhoId).startsWith(leadPrefix) ) {

                if(!LeadIds.contains(t.WhoId)){
                    LeadIds.add(t.WhoId);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    if(trigger.old!=null){
        for (Task t2 : Trigger.old) {
            if (t2.WhoId!= null && string.valueof(t2.WhoId).startsWith(leadPrefix) )
            {
                if(!LeadIds.contains(t2.WhoId)){

                    LeadIds.add(t2.WhoId);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (LeadIds.size() > 0){



        List<Lead> leadsWithTasks = [select id,Activity_Count__c,(select id from Tasks) from Lead where Id IN : Leadids];

        List<Lead> leadsUpdatable = new List<Lead>();

        for(Lead L : leadsWithTasks){

            L.Activity_Count__c = L.Tasks.size();
            leadsUpdatable.add(L);

        }

        if(leadsUpdatable.size()>0){

            update leadsUpdatable;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While you've done a good job avoiding some of the classic mistakes with first triggers (yay bulkification!) you'll still make your life easier if you just use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries rather than a trigger for this kind of rollup.

Comment: Can you possibly elaborate on that? I saw the declarative lookup roll-up link, but why over trigger?

Comment: DLRS is a pre-written solution. No code to write at all, just let it build the code for you. Of course, as a learning exercise, we could fix all the little mistakes in your code...

Comment: And DLRS already knows how to do things like filtering, handling record merges correctly, and so on. I will write up a straight answer as well, though.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll take a look at both David's write up below and then more into DLRS. I really appreciate the fast feedback

Answer (score 3):

Here's the *short* answer:

Add a `WHERE` clause to your task subquery:

```
    List<Lead> leadsWithTasks = [select Id, Activity_Count__c, (SELECT Id from Tasks) from Lead where Id IN :Leadids];
```

Make that `(SELECT Id FROM Tasks WHERE ... YOUR_CRITERIA_HERE)`.

You *could* also do some filtration on which Leads you ultimately query by checking, based upon the trigger event, whether the Task that's being affected is changing in such a way as to affect the count of Tasks that match your criteria. The additional code complexity may or may not be worth the perhaps-minor efficiency gain in the query, however.

That surmise could be wrong, especially if you have a ton of Tasks being altered on a regular basis.

Longer answer:

There's a few more things to fix here, although you've adopted the right architecture and structure to do this trigger well.

```
trigger TaskUpdateLead on Task (after delete, after insert, after undelete, after update) {

    Set<ID> LeadIds = new Set<ID>();
    String leadPrefix = Lead.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
```

You don't need to muck around with key prefixes when dealing with polymorphic lookup fields because you can look at `Who.Type` directly. I recently [wrote](https://www.ktema.org/2018/03/13/parent-child-soql-task-event/) a post on this subject.

```
    if (trigger.new!=null){
```

I see what you're doing here, but I think the logic would be clearer if you looked at the trigger events (`Trigger.isDelete`, etc.) Still, it makes sense. See below for another recommendation on reducing code duplication, though.

```
        for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
            if (t.WhoId!= null && string.valueof(t.WhoId).startsWith(leadPrefix) ) {
```

See above - you don't need to do the string manipulation here.

```
                if(!LeadIds.contains(t.WhoId)){
                    LeadIds.add(t.WhoId);
                }
```

You don't need to check a `Set` for membership before adding a member. That's the beauty of a `Set` - it is always deduplicated by nature.

```
            }
        }
    }

    if(trigger.old!=null){
        for (Task t2 : Trigger.old) {
            if (t2.WhoId!= null && string.valueof(t2.WhoId).startsWith(leadPrefix) )
            {
                if(!LeadIds.contains(t2.WhoId)){

                    LeadIds.add(t2.WhoId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All the same comments as above here. You could also tighten up this code by looking at the trigger event and assigning either `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.old` to a `List<Task>` local variable, and then iterate over that. (Only write the code once).

```
    if (LeadIds.size() > 0){
        List<Lead> leadsWithTasks = [select id,Activity_Count__c,(select id from Tasks) from Lead where Id IN : Leadids];
```

Here's where you can insert those criteria in the subquery. You do not need to select the existing value of `Activity_Count__c` since you're populating it on all of these Leads.

```
        List<Lead> leadsUpdatable = new List<Lead>();

        for(Lead L : leadsWithTasks){

            L.Activity_Count__c = L.Tasks.size();
            leadsUpdatable.add(L);

        }

        if(leadsUpdatable.size()>0){
            update leadsUpdatable;
        }
```

DML is a no-op on an empty list, so no need to check the size before doing `update`.

```
    }
}
```

Lastly, I would be remiss if I did not urge you to read up on *trigger frameworks*. You'll need one as your org and your codebase grow, but it's way better and cheaper to adopt right at the beginning.